# How to verify a signature in .net generated in Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, rsa, public-key-exchange

The problem is the following:

- I generate the key in Android (Xamarin.Droid):

  ```
   public IPublicKey CreateKey(string keyID)
   {
      /*KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(
               KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, "AndroidKeyStore");
      keyPairGenerator.initialize(
              new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                      "key1",
                      KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN)
                      .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
                      .setSignaturePaddings(KeyProperties.SIGNATURE_PADDING_RSA_PSS)
                      .build());
      KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
      Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA/PSS");
      signature.initSign(keyPair.getPrivate());

       // The key pair can also be obtained from the Android Keystore any time as follows:
       KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
                  keyStore.load(null);
                  PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey)keyStore.getKey("key1", null);
                  PublicKey publicKey = keyStore.getCertificate("key1").getPublicKey();*/


      //App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Info", "Creating a new key pair", "Ok");
      // UTILIZANDO RSA
      KeyPairGenerator kpg = 
      KeyPairGenerator.GetInstance(KeyProperties.KeyAlgorithmRsa, KEYSTORE_NAME);
      kpg.Initialize(
          new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(keyID,
          KeyStorePurpose.Sign)
          .SetSignaturePaddings(KeyProperties.SignaturePaddingRsaPss)
          .SetDigests(KeyProperties.DigestSha1)
          .Build()
          );

      KeyPair keyPair = kpg.GenerateKeyPair();

      Log.Debug(TAG, "New key created for fingerprint authentication");

      return keyPair.Public;
  }
  ```
- Then i generate a signature:

  ```
      KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry PKentry = 
      (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry)_keystore.GetEntry(keyID, null);
      IPublicKey pk = (IPublicKey)PKentry.Certificate.PublicKey;
      //this.pk = pk;
      privKey = PKentry.PrivateKey;

      //cipher.Init(Cipher.EncryptMode, privKey);
      //byte[] output = cipher.DoFinal(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
      //String s = new string(cipher.DoFinal(input));

      // signature
      Signature sig = Signature.GetInstance("SHA1withRSA/PSS");
      sig.InitSign(privKey);
      byte[] inputDataToSign = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
      sig.Update(inputDataToSign);
      byte[] signatureBytes = sig.Sign();
  ```
- And i send the key and the signature to a ASP.net wep API 2 server.
  Client side response generation:

  ```
   RegistrationResponse registrationResponse = new RegistrationResponse();
   string fcparams = Utils.Base64Encode(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(finalChallengeParams));
    registrationResponse.fcParams = fcparams;
    byte[] signedData = sign(fcparams, registrationRequest.username, facetID);
   registrationResponse.signedData = signedData;
   registrationResponse.Base64key = convertPublicKeyToString(publicKey);
   ...
   ...
  private string convertPublicKeyToString(IPublicKey publicKey)
  {
      string publicKeyString = Base64.EncodeToString(publicKey.GetEncoded(), 0);

   return publicKeyString;
    }
  ```

I send it using Refit Nugget.
And this is the code i use when i receive the HTTPRequest on server side:

```
[Route("regResponse/")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult ProcessClientRegistrationResponse([FromBody] RegistrationResponse registrationResponse) 
    {


        //byte[] publicKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(registrationResponse.Base64key);
        byte[] publicKeyBytes = registrationResponse.Base64key;
        AsymmetricKeyParameter asymmetricKeyParameter = PublicKeyFactory.CreateKey(publicKeyBytes);

        RsaKeyParameters rsaKeyParameters = (RsaKeyParameters)asymmetricKeyParameter;

        RSAParameters rsaParameters = new RSAParameters();
        rsaParameters.Modulus = rsaKeyParameters.Modulus.ToByteArrayUnsigned();
        rsaParameters.Exponent = rsaKeyParameters.Exponent.ToByteArrayUnsigned();

        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);

        /*****/

        string alg = rsa.SignatureAlgorithm;
        byte[] signedData = registrationResponse.signedData;
        byte[] fcParamsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(registrationResponse.fcParams);

        RSACng rsaCng = new RSACng();
        rsaCng.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);

        SHA1Managed hash = new SHA1Managed();
        byte[] hashedData;
        hashedData = hash.ComputeHash(signedData);


        /*********/

        bool rsaCngDataOk1 = rsaCng.VerifyData(fcParamsBytes, signedData, HashAlgorithmName.SHA1, RSASignaturePadding.Pss);
        bool rsaCngDataOk2 = rsaCng.VerifyData(fcParamsBytes, signedData, HashAlgorithmName.SHA1, RSASignaturePadding.Pss);
        bool rsaCngDataOk3 = rsaCng.VerifyData(hashedData, signedData, HashAlgorithmName.SHA1, RSASignaturePadding.Pss);
        bool rsaCngDataOk4 = rsaCng.VerifyData(hashedData, signedData, HashAlgorithmName.SHA1, RSASignaturePadding.Pss);

        bool rsaCngHashOk1 = rsaCng.VerifyHash(hashedData, signedData, HashAlgorithmName.SHA1, RSASignaturePadding.Pss);

        bool dataOK1 = rsa.VerifyData(fcParamsBytes, new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider(), signedData);
        bool dataOk2 = rsa.VerifyData(fcParamsBytes, signedData, HashAlgorithmName.SHA1, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

        bool hashOk = rsa.VerifyHash(hashedData, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"), signedData);

        return Ok(true);

    }
```

EVERY bool is wrong. I think the problem is clearly on the public key.
The questions are,

1. does the method publickey.encode() do what i think? I think it converts my public key to a byte[] representation (source: [Android developer Key Info](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/Key.html#getEncoded()))
2. do i convert the received byte[] representation of the key to a correct RSA key?
3. Is there any problem on algorithms? I don't think so but we never know...

I don't find the solution. I searched for ways to import public keys from strings in .net or c# and for ways to export Android Public key to string or byte[] but there's no much help for this concrete questions...

Comment: `PublicKeyFactory.CreateKey(publicKeyBytes);` is very likely to throw an exception unless the publickey byte array contains something that parses like a SubjectPublicKeyInfo ASN1 -encoded object. I would focus on the encoding(or lack of it) on the signed data itself, and verify that it is transferred correctly.

Comment: @JamesKPolk it doesn't throw any exception. The code runs without any problem

Comment: Exactly. That's why I said you should "...focus on the encoding(or lack of it) on the signed data itself, and verify that it is transferred correctly."

Comment: I verified debugging and it's exactly the same data on both sides. Even the key is the same. I compared the modulus and the exponent from the public key on the client side and the one received by the server. They are both the same so it seems like the public key is well received by the server. But the problem persists

Comment: Ok, I will attempt to duplicate your results in my own test environment.

Comment: I created my own example that was as faithful to yours as I could be. I don't have access to a Windows platform, so I'm using Mono on Mac OSx, but it doesn't support PSS. However, when I use Pkcs1 padding it verifies just fine. I would guess that your encoding/decoding of the data is the problem.

Comment: How do you use PKcs1 padding on Android? I can't find any "string" with pcks1 as padding  [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/Signature.html#getInstance(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
Really thanks for helping

Comment: IT WORKED!! IT WORKED!!! MANY THANKS!!!! FOREVER GRATITUDE!!!  PSS seems to be the problem...

Comment: Sure thing, but note that PSS is the more modern and secure signature scheme and should be used in preference to "pkcs1" in new applications.

Comment: Yes i know it. But unfortunately it doens't work =(

Answer (score 0):

@James K Polk gave me the solution.
Apparently C# doesn't work well with PSS padding. I just had to change it to PKCS1. And i changed to digest algorithm too to SHA512.